# Check a bash variable against a file

Tags: shell, files, string, busybox

I have a bash variable ($HTTP_COOKIE) which contains a string. I want to check if this string matches the content of a given file (token). I'm working on a busybox linux.

How should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by “matches”? That file contains a regular expression?

Comment: I mean that "match exactly byte per byte" the content of the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 if [ "x$HTTP_COOKIE" = "x$(cat myfile)" ]
  then
    ....
```

keep the x in front in case the string may start with a minus sign (in that case it would be considered as an option to the command *test* (`[ ... ]`).

Comment: There's a bug in that code: `$()` removes trailing newlines, so you should check `"x${HTTP_COOKIE}x" = "x$(cat myfile; echo x)"`

Comment: Valid if the string in question contains newlines, but most of the times one wants to get rid of newlines.